# Find and click on all the webelements with same locator

Tags: java, selenium, tabs

I am trying to find all the *Continue Reading* in a random facebook page and open them in a new tab.

First find a post that contains *Continue Reading*, open it new tab, after some actions are done in the page that is opened as a new tab, it will close, then find the second *Continue Reading* post, if any, open in new tab, do some actions and close, continue process until there is no more *Continue Reading* posts.

The codes below is what I have written to achieve the above.

```
    List <WebElement> continuereading = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='text_exposed_link']//a[@target='_blank' and contains (text(), 'Continue Reading')]"));

    System.out.println(continuereading);
    for (int i=0; i <= continuereading.size(); i++){   
        //check if there is continue reading element in post
        if (continuereading.size() > 0) {
            WebElement contreading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='text_exposed_link']//a[@target='_blank' and contains (text(), 'Continue Reading')]"));

            //open link in new tab
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform();
            //scroll to the element 
            jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", contreading);
            contreading.click();
            action.keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform();

            //close new tab
            action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0077')).perform();
            action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0077')).perform();

        }
    }
```

**Problem** As the *Continue Reading* element will not disappear after clicking, the first element is continuously clicked on and opened in a new tab till the loop ends, while the other *Continue Reading* elements will not be clicked on at all.

Is there a way to solve this problem that will enable all the *Continue Reading* element to be found and clicked on?

Comment: I don't know specific of `Java`, but in `Python` `continuereading` variable is a list of elements. And each of these elements can be called by its index: `continuereading[0]`, `continuereading[1]` (`continuereading[i]` in `for` loop) instead of calling by `driver.findElement()` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because inside your `for` loop you're getting the element again.

```
WebElement contreading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='text_exposed_link']//a[@target='_blank' and contains (text(), 'Continue Reading')]"));
```

This particular line will always get you the first element on the page and click on it (exactly what you're experiencing).
Instead, just do:

```
for (int i=0; i < continuereading.size(); i++){
    //open link in new tab
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform();
            //scroll to the element 
            jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", continuereading.get(i));
            continuereading.get(i).click();
            action.keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform();

            //close new tab
            action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0077')).perform();
            action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0077')).perform();

        }
```

Note that I also fixed your `for` loop iteration. You were iterating from `0` to `list.size()` included and that will eventually throw and `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.